# ImageSharp: Corner rounding transparency fades dark instead of light

Tags: c#, image, .net-core, imagesharp

I'm using the ImageSharp library (available on NuGet as 1.0.0-beta0001) for image generation and manipulation in .NET Core 2.0, and have encountered something that I can't seem to find a way around.

Using [this example](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/tree/master/samples/AvatarWithRoundedCorner) as a basis, I'm trying to round the corners of a white image. What I'm finding is that the transparent `IPath` corners being punched out end up antialiasing dark, as if the transparent "color" were black or gray (whereas it really shouldn't be considered any color at all).

Here's the upper-right quadrant of the image to demonstrate what I mean:

[image: Antialiasing Desired vs Result]

I tried all the options for `PixelBlenderMode` at this part of the code and none have produced what I'm after:

```
img.Mutate(x => x.Fill(Rgba32.Transparent, corners, new GraphicsOptions(true)
{
  BlenderMode = PixelBlenderMode.Src // enforces that any part of this shape that has color is punched out of the background
}));
```

Comment: Give ImageMagic a go https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET-Q16-x86/

Comment: Can you provide a sample source image?

Comment: There is no source image in this case, it's being generated.

Comment: "Transparent" is probably colour (0,0,0,0); transparent _black_. For white edges, you may want to instead paint with transparent _white_: (0,255,255,255). At the edges, it can make a difference what colour value is accompanying the transparency, since said colour is also mixing with your edge colours.

Comment: @Nyerguds: That makes perfect sense! Unfortunately, it made no difference when I tried it just now. It may be something about this library.

Comment: Could also be that the colour under the transparent area around that shape is actually black, and the transparency fade reveals that. In that case, it could be fixed by painting an extra white edge along the outer border of the fade, before applying the fade itself.

Comment: In the end, I chose to switch to ImageMagick. I was able to migrate all my code in a couple of hours. Not exactly the solution I had hoped for, but I couldn't figure this out with ImageSharp, which has too many quirks right now for me to feel confident in pushing it to a production server anyway.

Comment: @AntonToshik Simply recommending another library is unhelpful.

Comment: @DJGrossman please raise any issues you have on the repository issue tracker.

Comment: @JamesSouth that's why I put it as a comment and not an answer, and he can try it, if it works it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is the consequence of incorrect pixel sampling. Pixels with low transparency were affecting the average value of the individual components too much.

Quoting some of the text from below link as an example as it explains the issues well.

> A pixel in the white area has a color of **RGBA(1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)**. A pixel in the red area has color **RGBA(1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.10)**. If you average those numbers together, you get **(1.00, 0.50, 0.50, 0.55)**. That’s the color a typical pixel on the boundary would have if you resize the image in the straightforward way.
>   But that color – a half-opaque light red – is the wrong color! You can see a faint red halo around the border, which shouldn’t be there:

http://entropymine.com/imageworsener/resizealpha/

The fix is simple, values must be premultiplied by their alpha component first before sampling.

However, I don't know whether this issue is happening due to resizing the generated image (fixed in the latest nightlies), or during the fill process. I would need to see sample code first to be sure as I do not know how you are providing the source image.

Comment: When I have a moment, I'll look in my repository to see if I checked in the ImageSharp implementation previously.

Comment: Great, please let me know how you get on.